# Create frame by frame animation inside movie Clip AS3 - Adobe air

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an adobe air application running on both Android and iOS platforms. In the app, i am calling several movie clips to stage, so there will always be several movie clips coming to stage. Exactly, i have 6 different movie clips, and i am calling them each time 6/5/4 times. 
I want to make them animated, as in go to the library, go into the movie clip, and create a frame by frame animation.
I have tried to create 25 PNG images , 300 dpi , 40x40 size. The animation works correctly, but the problem is whenever i run the app on any device, the response time would be enormous, causing the app to crash sometimes. It seems that if i did a frame by frame animation, with high resolution PNGs , the app will be too slow to use. 
I need to have a nice quality for each image in the movie clip, but i guess doing so with high quality PNGs is not the best approach to use. I thought maybe importing several illustrator file and spreading them on each frame could do so. But i'm not sure whether the mobile device could achieve the best quality/performance ratio. 
 Therefor, how can i achieve the best quality/performance ratio in Flash CS6 , AS3 adobe air targeting mobile devices ?

**Edit :**

I have the movie clip created and in the library, inside of it i have loaded one PNG image. I tried to : 
Convert the image inside that movie clip to a movie clip, and took care of all the needed names just to confirm with the answer suggested. The father movie clip is linked to a AS class, in which i tried to insert the suggested code, but what happened is, the movie clips stopped appearing from the stage at all. Am i missing something ?

Comment: 300dpi is meaningless and only relevant for print. Chances are the performance problem comes from the way you use the images. But you haven't shown your code. Also, why don't you create that frame by frame animation in flash? After all it is an animation software.

Comment: You should be putting everything in bitmaps. Bitmaps use the GPU, vectors and PNG use the CPU. Bitmap optimization is definitely necessary for smooth animation on mobile. Because you're doing Android and Android has so many different screen dimensions and dpi, you should draw things in vector, resize the vectors to fit the device, convert the vectors to bitmaps. I can give you more info and example code if you think this is the answer to your question.

Comment: @moot i guess yes it is the right way to through, i've created several illustrator files, each one representing one frame from the animation, do you think i should save them as bitmap and import them frame by frame to the movie clip in flash ? or can i import them as eps or something ? what do you think is the best approach ?

Comment: Just highlight, copy and paste the vectors directly from illustrator to the original animate. That way you can resize the vectors for the device display dimensions, convert to bitmap, then delete the vector. Here is example code showing how to convert a movieclip into a bitmap and remove the original: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775200/air-for-android-animation-causes-lagging-in-my-game/31819086#31819086

Comment: I made a mistake. That wasn't a good code example in my previous comment. It was using copyPixels. You need to use draw to convert a movieclip to bitmap. I posted good example code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting everything in bitmaps. Bitmaps use the GPU, vectors and PNG use the CPU. Bitmap optimization is definitely necessary for smooth animation on mobile. Because you're doing Android and Android has so many different screen dimensions and dpi, you should draw things in vector, resize the vectors to fit the device, convert the vectors to bitmaps.

Here's example code to convert a movieclip to a bitmap. The original movieclip - mcCircleVector - is inside a holder movieclip - mcCircle. The code converts mcCircleVector to bitmap, removes it, and adds the bitmap to mcCircle so you end up with a movieclip.

```
var bmpTemp: Bitmap;
bmpTemp = new Bitmap();
bmpTemp = fConvertToBMP(mcCircle.mcCircleVector, 150, 150);
mcCircle.removeChild(mcCircle.mcCircleVector);
mcCircle.mcCircleVector = null;
mcCircle.addChild(bmpTemp);
bmpTemp = null;


private function convertBMP(pClip: MovieClip, pWidth: int, pHeight: int): Bitmap {
    var bd: BitmapData = new BitmapData(pWidth, pHeight, true, 0x00000000);
    bd.draw(pClip, null, null, null, null, true);
    var bmp: Bitmap = new Bitmap(bd, "auto", false);
    bmp.smoothing = true;
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: please check my Edit, i tried it but i guess i am missing something