# Actionscript 3: Pre rendering instance of class to improve performance

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a few classes which create large numbers of buttons with event listeners that get created and positioned. I currently re use the instance of the class once created to improve the user experience in terms of time between clicking a button and the list appearing. I wish to improve it when the user first causes the instance to be created.

So I am now creating an instance during app start-up and storing for later use.

This looks like this:

```
_MenuView = new MenuView();
_MenuView.visible = false;
addChild(_MenuView);
removeChild(_MenuView);
_MenuView.visible = true;
```

Is this a good approach?

Comment: Opinion-based answer. No, it's totally wrong - but not in the way you might think. Did you try to measure how long does it take to create all these buttons? Or the impact of adding them to the display list for the first/second time? If there's no problem (no lag with the weakest device config), trying to solve it might do a **nasty** trick on you and there **will** be a problem.

Comment: I have 3 classes which take a total of 4 seconds to create on an average Android device, about 2 seconds on a newer iOS device and almost instantly on a core i7 pc. So I am getting about 1.3 second lag on click for each class the first time created on Android.

Comment: Do you use regular Flash content? I mean, rather than Starling or any other Stage3D framework.

Comment: Regular actionscript flash project in Flash Builder, deployed to mobille and desktop. I have already optimised the button creation code, its very fast for one button but when I have 150 its not so.

Comment: It's render. You will never get any decent performance with regular Flash content. Flash uses CPU for render (even if you set some publish option to "GPU" - the option helps in certain limited cases) while mobile devices just don't have such amounts of CPU power. Consider porting your project to Starling - the only way to have Flash run smoothly on mobile device is to actually use its GPU to render content.

Comment: Yeah, for mobile, everything has to be converted to bitmap. In general, bitmap is on the GPU, everything else is on the CPU. Here's example code for converting regular movieclips to bitmap: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775200/air-for-android-animation-causes-lagging-in-my-game/31819086#31819086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks good to me. I tend to use a similar approach. If you have something unchanging like a menu that looks the same every time it appears, it makes sense to not have to create it over and over again, given that it doesn't take up too much memory. On that note, make sure everything that you are recreating multiple times gets garbage-collected so that you don't get memory leaks.